# Create custom logging function for pythons logging module

Tags: python, inheritance, logging, python-logging

I have been trying for some time to figure out how to create a custom function for the python logging module. My goal is, with the usual function such as `logging.debug(...)` a log message over several channels, such as Telegram or MQTT, to publishing. So my idea is to add extra arguments to the normal log methode. For example `logging.debug ("a log", telegram=True, mqtt=False)` and maybe other arguments. All I find is the inheritance of the class logging.StreamingHandler and then using the method emit, but this only passes the argument record. So how can I implement my problem in a meaningful way? Do I have a thinking error or the wrong approach?

Comment: You should subclass `StreamHandler` for pushing a message to telegram (`TelegramHandler`) and mqtt, then register multiple handlers to a single `Logger`. If you wanted a logger that logs to telegram and mqtt, for instance, register your telegram and mqtt handlers to it. Monkey-patching methods to add telegram and mqtt functionality is always an option, but is a last resort only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a interface for the logging module.

A small view on my code:

```
# ulogging.py
import logging
import telegram

def uloggingConfig(*args, **kwargs):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # general logging config section
    fmt = kwargs.pop("fmt", "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s")
    datefmt = kwargs.pop("datefmt", "%m.%d.%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

    streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    streamHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formater = logging.Formatter(fmt=fmt, datefmt=datefmt)
    streamHandler.setFormatter(formater)
    logger.addHandler(streamHandler)

    # telegram config section
    telegramBot = kwargs.pop("teleBot", None)
    telegramChatID = kwargs.pop("teleChatID", None)
    telegramLevel = kwargs.pop("teleLevel", logging.INFO)
    telegramFmt = kwargs.pop("telefmt", "%(message)s")
    telegramDatefmt = kwargs.pop("teledatefmt", None)

    if telegramBot is not None and telegramChatID is not None:
        telegramStream = TelegramStream(telegramBot, telegramChatID)
        formater = logging.Formatter(fmt=telegramFmt, datefmt=telegramDatefmt)
        telegramStream.setFormatter(formater)
        telegramStream.setLevel(telegramLevel)
        logger.addHandler(telegramStream)
    elif (telegramBot is not None and telegramChatID is None) or (telegramBot is None and telegramChatID is not None):
        raise KeyError("teleBot and teleChatID have to be both given")

    if kwargs:
        keys = ', '.join(kwargs.keys())
        raise ValueError('Unrecognised argument(s): %s' % keys)

    return logger

def getLogger():
    return logging.getLogger(__name__)

class TelegramStream(logging.StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, telegramBot, telegramChatID):
        logging.StreamHandler.__init__(self)
        self._bot = telegramBot
        self._chatID = telegramChatID

    def emit(self, record):
        if record.levelname == "DEBUG":
            self._bot.send_message(self._chatID, record.levelname + ": " + record.msg)
        else:
            self._bot.send_message(self._chatID, record.msg)
```

With the uloggingConfig() method I can now pass all settings for the different handlers (at the moment only for telegram, further handlers should follow). The uloggingConfig() method then takes over the configuration and returns a logger with which log messages can be created as usual.

A simple example:

```
logger = ulogging.uloggingConfig(fmt="format, datefmt="dateformat, teleBot=telegramBot, teleChatID=telegramChatID, teleLevel=logging.DEBUG)

logger.debug("A log message")
```